# Identify the physical system that corresponds to the Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator

Let a system's Lagrangian be given by $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2) - mgz - \frac{1}{2}m(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$ (The $x$, $y$, $z$ coordinates denote the cartesian coordinates, $m$,$a$ are constants).

If you convert them to cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$, you get $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2+\dot{z}^2) - mgz - \frac{1}{2}m(r^2+z^2).$$

I thought it might be a simple harmonic oscillator, but I'm not quite sure about that... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try to write down the corresponding equations of motion? This could help you to identify the physical system.

Comment: Hint: Complete the square!

Comment: How will that help? @Qmechanic

Comment: I found the equations of motions and solved them; the $x, y, z$ follow a motion similar to the simple oscillator.

Comment: $L=\dfrac{1}{2}m\cdot \left( \dfrac{d\overrightarrow{r}}{dt}\right) ^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}m\left( \overrightarrow{r}\right) ^{2}-mg\overrightarrow{r}\cdot \widehat{e}_{z}$

Comment: Will it be a hanging spring in 3 dimensions?

Comment: Yes $\overrightarrow{r}=\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: It is a 3d SHO with gravity.  The complete the square hint will help you realize that all g does is change the equilibrium position.  You are left with a pure quadratic.